# Finding $\lim\limits _{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^3+x}}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim\limits _{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^3+x}}{x}$$

I have to resolve this limit, I tried factoring out x, I tried rewriting $x^3+x$ as 
$x^3(1+ \frac{x}{x^3})$ and it doesn't seem to cancel. What should I do?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt[3]{x^3+x}= x\sqrt[3]{1 + \frac{1}{x^2}}$. Then cancel the $x$ here with the $x$ in the denominator and go from there.

Answer (score 9):

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^3+x}}{x}=\lim_{x\to-\infty} \sqrt[3]{\frac{x^3+x}{x^3}} =\lim_{x\to-\infty} \sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}  = \sqrt[3]{1+\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}}=1$$

Comment: So check your problem again :)

Comment: Thank you! I was looking at the wrong answer, I got 1 too at some point and I thought that I should get +infinity from the answer I was looking. I need to be more careful! :D

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt[\,3]{x^3+x}}{x}
=&
\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt[\,3]{x^3\cdot(1+1/x^2)}}{x}
\\
=&
\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt[\,3]{x^3}\cdot\sqrt[\,3]{(1+1/x^2)}}{x}
\\
=&
\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{x\cdot\sqrt[\,3]{(1+1/x^2)}}{x}
\\
=&
\lim_{x\to -\infty} {\sqrt[\,3]{(1+1/x^2)}}
\\
=&
{\sqrt[\,3]{\lim_{x\to -\infty} (1+1/x^2)}}
\\
=&
 {\sqrt[\,3]{(1+\lim_{x\to -\infty} (1/x^2))}}
\\
=&
 {\sqrt[\,3]{(1+0)}}
\\
=&
 {\sqrt[\,3]{1}}
\\
=&
1
\end{align}